# How to query nested objects?

Tags: mongodb, syntax, nested, mongodb-query, bson

I have a problem when querying mongoDB with nested objects notation:

```
db.messages.find( { headers : { From: "reservations@marriott.com" } } ).count()
0
db.messages.find( { 'headers.From': "reservations@marriott.com" }  ).count()
5
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. I am expecting nested object notation to return the same result as the dot notation query. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 585, accepted):

`db.messages.find( { headers : { From: "reservations@marriott.com" } } )`

This queries for documents where `headers` *equals* `{ From: ... }`, i.e. contains no other fields.

---

`db.messages.find( { 'headers.From': "reservations@marriott.com" }  )`

This only looks at the `headers.From` field, not affected by other fields contained in, or missing from, `headers`.

---

[Dot-notation docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without the quotes around "headers.From"?

Comment: I don't know, just wondering, and thought it may sometimes be useful.

Comment: @trysis - In practice, I have found that declaring inline objects (like the examples in mongo[ose] docs, and in most examples out there) simply isn't enough in the real world. I have developed the habit of creating 'conditions' and 'fields' objects on which I can do stuff like `conditions['some.path'] = 'value'` in my business logic, then run a single query at the end: `find(conditions, fields, callback);`

Comment: What if let's say I have a key which contains "domain.com", this will not work: `domains.domain.com`. Is there any workaround for this scenario (without altering the domain.com to something else e.g domain_com)?

Comment: Answering my own comment, it's best to avoid using dots completely in your keys. In my solution I completely ditched the domains being keys, and created a slice/array instead.

Answer (score 35):

Since there is a lot of confusion about **queries MongoDB collection with sub-documents**, I thought its worth to explain the above answers with examples:

First I have inserted only two objects in the collection namely: `message` as:

```
> db.messages.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cce8e417d2e7b3fe9c93c32"),
    "headers" : {
        "From" : "reservations@marriott.com"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cce8eb97d2e7b3fe9c93c33"),
    "headers" : {
        "From" : "reservations@marriott.com",
        "To" : "kprasad.iitd@gmail.com"
    }
}
>
```

> So what is the result of query: `db.messages.find({headers: {From: "reservations@marriott.com"}  }).count()`

It should be **one** because these queries for documents where `headers` equal to the object `{From: "reservations@marriott.com"}`, only i.e. contains no other fields or we should specify the entire sub-document as the value of a field.

So as per the answer from @Edmondo1984

> > Equality matches within sub-documents select documents if the subdocument matches **exactly the specified sub-document, including the field order**.

From the above statements, what is the below query result should be?

```
> db.messages.find({headers: {To: "kprasad.iitd@gmail.com", From: "reservations@marriott.com"}  }).count()
0
```

And what if we will change the order of `From` and `To` i.e same as sub-documents of second documents?

```
> db.messages.find({headers: {From: "reservations@marriott.com", To: "kprasad.iitd@gmail.com"}  }).count()
1
```

> so, it matches **exactly the specified sub-document, including the field order**.

For using dot operator, I think it is very clear for every one. Let's see the result of below query:

```
> db.messages.find( { 'headers.From': "reservations@marriott.com" }  ).count()
2
```

I hope these explanations with the above example will make someone more clarity on **find query with sub-documents**.

Comment: Will it be the same if I use populate method after the find method? `        const notes = await Note2.find({"note.title": "some-title"}).populate("note")` Here I'm populating the field note and in that field I have a title that I need to use for the find method. But it returns an empty array. Why does that happen? Can you please take a look at the question regarding this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73659370/14835590

Answer (score 31):

The two query mechanism work in different ways, as suggested in [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/core/read-operations/#subdocuments) at the section *Subdocuments*:

When the field holds an embedded document (i.e, *subdocument*), you can either specify the entire *subdocument* as the value of a field, or “reach into” the *subdocument* using dot notation, to specify values for individual fields in the *subdocument*:

Equality matches within subdocuments select documents if the subdocument matches exactly the specified subdocument, including the field order.

---

In the following example, the query matches all documents where the value of the field producer is a subdocument that contains only the field `company` with the value `'ABC123'` and the field `address` with the value `'123 Street'`, in the exact order:

```js
db.inventory.find( {
    producer: {
        company: 'ABC123',
        address: '123 Street'
    }
});
```

Comment: I was going crazy. This seems to me quite inconsistent, because when querying objects it's direct properties can be matched in any order.

Answer (score -1):

```
    //Simple and best solution complete code with example
    
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose
      .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test")
      .then(() => console.log("Connected!"));
    const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title: String,
      author: String,
      body: String,
    
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      hidden: Boolean,
      meta: {
        votes: Number,
        favs: Number,
      },
    });
    const Bloging = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
    const createDocument = async () => {
      const doc = new Bloging({
        title: "node js",
        author: "adil",
        body: "Monngose Traning",
    
        hidden: true,
        meta: {
          votes: 1000,
          favs: 30,
        },
      });
      const doc2 = new Bloging({
        title: "vue js",
        author: "adil",
        body: "Monngose Traning",
    
        hidden: true,
        meta: {
          votes: 20,
          favs: 80,
        },
      });
      const doc3 = new Bloging({
        title: "React js",
        author: "adil",
        body: "Monngose Traning",
    
        hidden: true,
        meta: {
          votes: 30,
          favs: 60,
        },
      });
      await Bloging.insertMany([doc, doc2, doc3]); // Throws "document must have an _id before saving"
    };
    const getDocument = async () => {
      const result = await Bloging.find({ "meta.favs": { $gt: 60 } });
      console.log(result);
    };
 createDocument();
    getDocument();
   
    
        enter code here
    
    **strong text**
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).