# mongo query doesn't return results

Tags: python, mongodb, database

I have a document like this is database

```
{
    "timestamp" : "2016-06-27T14:29:22.091Z",
    "story" : "This is the story of how I was harassed.",
    "latitude": 42.23424364766,
    "longitude": 21.13243546545,
    "event": {
        "region": "Albania",
        "language": "English",
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

under `event` key is `region`. It can be different.

Now using python, I want to make a query on mongodb and I want to return only the documents that have  `"event" : {'region': region}` 
`region` is a parameter that can change.

```
def get_all_event_based_on_region(self,region):
    query = { "event" : {'region': region}}
    ...
    docs = self._get(query)
    return list(docs)
```

But this query return nothing cause  there are other fields like `language and version`, how can I modify this query so it will  works?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [How to query nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/mongodb-how-to-query-nested-objects) - you need to transform your query into:

```
query = {"event.region": region}
```