# Query to Match on nth Document of an Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and I am doing some exercises on it. In particular I got stuck on [this exercise](http://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/mongodb-exercise-23.php), of which I report here the question:

Given the following structure for document "Restaurant":

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5704adbc2eb7ebe23f582818"),
        "address" : {
                "building" : "1007",
                "coord" : [
                        -73.856077,
                        40.848447
                ],
                "street" : "Morris Park Ave",
                "zipcode" : "10462"
        },
        "borough" : "Bronx",
        "cuisine" : "Bakery",
        "grades" : [
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 2
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 6
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-01-24T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 10
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 9
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2011-03-10T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "B",
                        "score" : 14
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Morris Park Bake Shop",
        "restaurant_id" : "30075445"
}
```

> Write a MongoDB query to find the restaurant Id, name and grades for those restaurants where 2nd element of grades array contains a grade of "A" and score 9 on an ISODate "2014-08-11T00:00:00Z".

I wrote this query:

```
db.restaurants.find(
{
    'grades.1': {
        'score': 'A',
        'grade': 9,
        'date' : ISODate("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z")
    }
},
{
    restaurant_id: 1,
    name: 1,
    grades: 1
});
```

which is not working.
The solution provided is the following:

```
db.restaurants.find( 
    { "grades.1.date": ISODate("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"), 
      "grades.1.grade":"A" , 
      "grades.1.score" : 9
    }, 
    {"restaurant_id" : 1,"name":1,"grades":1}
);
```

My questions are:

1. is there a way to write the query avoiding to repeat the `grades.1` part?
2. Why is my query wrong, given that `grades.1` is a document object?

If it can help answering my question, I am using `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4`

*EDIT*:

I found an answer to question 2 thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/mongodb-how-to-query-nested-objects).

In particular I discovered that **order matters**. Indeed, if I perform the following query, I get a valid result:

```
db.restaurants.find({'grades.1': {'date': ISODate("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"), 'grade':'A', score:9}}, {restaurant_id:1, name:1, grades:1})
```

Note that this query works only because **all** subdocument's "fields" are specified, and they are specified in the same order.

Comment: This is not a valid document because field names cannot start with `$`

Comment: That's true, they provided a wrong structure. I corrected it with the real one

Comment: You should use a valid `date` also since it appears in your query criteria.

Comment: @user3100115 I now pasted the result of `db.restaurants.find().limit(1)`, so you have a valid and well-formed document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. But perhaps an explanation of what you "can" do:

```js
  db.junk.find({
    "grades": { 
      "$elemMatch": {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 2
      }
    },
    "$where": function() {
      var grade = this.grades[0];
      return (
        grade.date.valueOf() == ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z").valueOf() &&
        grade.grade === "A" &&
        grade.score ==== 2
      )
    }
  })
```

The [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) allows you to shorten a little, but it is not the "nth" element of the array. In order to narrow that further you need to use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause to inspect the "nth" array element to see if all values are a match.

```js
  db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
      "grades": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
          "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z"),
          "grade" : "A",
          "score" : 2
        }
      }
    }},
    { "$redact": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
          "$let": {
            "vars": { "grade": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$grades", 0 ] } },
            "in": {
              "$and": [
                { "$eq": [ "$grade.date", ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z") ] },
                { "$eq": [ "$grade.grade", "A" ] },
                { "$eq": [ "$grade.score", 2 ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
      }
    }}
  ])
```

You can do the same logic with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as well using `.aggregate()`. It runs a little quicker, but the basic truth should be clear by now.

So using ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to specify the "nth" position for each element within the array like you have already done **is** the most efficient and "brief" way to write this. You cannot make it shorter or better.

Your other attempt is looking for a "document" within `"grades.1"` that matches **exactly** the document condition you are providing. If for any reason those are not the **only** fields present, or if they are indeed in "different order" in the stored document, then such a query condition **will not** be a match.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to avoid repeating "unnecessary" repetitions (or, at least, what I thought it was a unnecessary), saving a few characters. Unfortunately it seems that in order to save characters I need to repeat all the conditions :) In this particular case, however, I can save a few chars by using the query I appended to my question. EDIT: I just saw your edit to the answer!

Comment: @user2340612 So the "dot notation" method is the best in brevity and efficiency. It would be "nice" if you could somehow do `"grades.0": { "$elemMatch": { ... } }`, but of course you cannot since the element is already "deferenced" as an "Object" by this point. Both `$elemMatch` and "dot notation" exist to combat the "exact match" problem.

Comment: Yeah, a solution like `"grades.0": {"$elemMatch": {...} }`, with the advantages of the "dot notation" (w.r.t. the "exact match" problem) and the brevity of the "exact match" notation would be great in this case