# Express/MongoDB: how to get a value from a nested field

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query, mean-stack, database-schema

First I'm sorry if I'm not using the right words or if the question is silly, I'm very new to this and still learning, and this time I wasn't able to find an answer with my search!

I have a MEAN project, and I want to get a value from my database on my front-end (I use Angular 4). So I tried writing a function on Express, but the fact is I don't know how, since I'm not even able to get the value directly in command line in mongo.

My schema has this format:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    item: {
        item1: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        item2: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        item3: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Idea is that each user has an inventory with a certain number of each item, and my goal is to fetch this specific number when doing a request with the item name.

But the best I was able to do is db.users.find({}, {item:1}); with which I got the whole list of items with their values, every other things I tried got me an error. So maybe my schema isn't right?

So my question is:
**How can I only get the item value with Express by passing the item name as parameter, knowing I'm not currently able to get the value directly from mongo?**

Knowing the answer will help me too to know how to change this value later on.

Thank you for reading!

[EDIT]
This topic was marked as duplicate with this one:
[How to query nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/how-to-query-nested-objects)

But I saw this other topic already, so yes, with:

```
db.users.find({ item : { item1 : "0" }}).count();
```

I can get the value, but it doesn't help me at all, because you have to write the value to get the value.... but I want to make a query WITHOUT knowing the value, because this value will change.

Plus, it's more on the Express side that I need advices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query would be something like this:

```
db.users.find({ username: "someuser" }, { "item.item1": 1, "_id": 0 })
```

The *1* indicates that you want to get that field, it doesn't represent its value. _id is usually always returned, so I set it to *0* to not return it in this particular case. Item name was passed as a parameter; in this case, it's *item1*.

The query would return something like this:

```
{ "item" : [ { "item1" : 123 } ] }
```

It's ordinary JSON so the value can easily be extracted.

In Mongoose it would be something like this:

```
const itemname = 'item1';

User
  .findOne(
    { username: 'someuser' },
    { [`item.${itemname}`]: true, _id: false },
    (err, result) => {
      const response = {};

      if (err) {
        response.status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        response.message = err;
      } else {
        response.status = HttpStatus.OK;
        response.message = result.item[itemname];
      }

      return res.status(response.status).json(response.message);
    }
  );
```

Without proper error handling. The code snippet fails if the user doesn't exist, doesn't have the item field and so on.