# mongoose greater than for nested property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a user model like so

```
requestCashout: {
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
}
```

I want to get all the users which has amount of greater than 0, I did this

```
exports.getUsersRequestCashout = async function(req, res, next) {
  const users = await User.find(
    { role: 'member', {'requestCashout.amount': $gt: 0} },
    {
      fullName: 1,
      requestCashout: 1
    }
  ).exec()

  res.json({
    status: 1,
    data: users
  })
}
```

Why `requestCashout.amount` doesn't seem valid?

Comment: Should be `'requestCashout.amount': { $gt: 0 }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/how-to-query-nested-objects)