# Use a filter in a Mongoose JS find() function that includes an object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My model looks like this:

```
  {
    visibleIn: { order: false, showcase: true, search: true },
    _id: qijjdjrby0ytnaznj2dk,
    name: 'iPhone 7 + Black, Grey, or Rose-Gold',
    __v: 0
  }
```

I named this model Product, so `const Product = require('../path/to/file')`.
I'm trying to find all Products that have an `order` of `true` when I use the `find()` method.  I thought something like this would have worked:

```
Product.find({visibleIn.order: true});
```

Results in `Unexpected token '.'` error

or

```
Product.find({visibleIn: {order: true}});
```

Results in an empty array `[]`

So how do I use a filter if it's inside another object?

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/how-to-query-nested-objects)

Comment: as mentioned above ^ the solution is to use a string for the key:
`Product.find({visibleIn.order: true});`
should be:
`Product.find({'visibleIn.order': true});`
I haven't tested it, but I've used it before in my own code, give it a try and let us know

Comment: nax3t, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nax3t for answering my question (but did so in a comment, so don't ding me for answering the question).  Instead of

```
Product.find({visibleIn.order: true});
```

I need to use

```
Product.find({'visibleIn.order': true});
```

This is because of the way Mongoose passes object arguments to itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.find({visibleIn.order: true});
```

have you tried this?
you can use this to filter your DB

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I have tried that.  To answer Nico Haase's request, the reason for the code above is because objects can be written as two notations: `object.property` and `object['property']`.  Both will call `property`.