# Delete document in mongodb collection with deleteOne where data is an object with the id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, agenda, mongoose-deleteone

Im trying to delete a record in my mongodb collection that look like this

```
{
    "name": "do sftp backup",
    "data": {
        "scheduleId": 95
    },
    "priority": 0,
    "type": "normal",
    "nextRunAt": null,
    "lastModifiedBy": null,
    "lockedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-03T23:02:44.879Z"
    },
    "lastRunAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-03T23:02:54.874Z"
    }
}
```

but in need to do the query to find this record by the scheduleId in the data field

this is what im doing in the controller

```
db.collection('agendaJobs').deleteOne({data: scheduleId}, (error) => {
      if(!error) {
          console.log('Successfully deleted ');
          console.log(error);
          client.close();

      } else {
          console.log(error);
          client.close();
      }
  })
```

and getting the id by params through postman like this localhost:3000/api/schedule/95

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/how-to-query-nested-objects)

Comment: i tried both ways specified in that question, like this     const findResult = await collection.find({data: {scheduleId: "95"}})
    const findResult = await collection.find({'data.scheduleId':"95"}) but none of them gives me a result, the second one returns a result but nothing to do with the looking document

Comment: also tried doing {'data.scheduleId':95} in the query input in the mongoDB compass and it returns the matching document, but in the code even if is hardcored like this     const findResult = await collection.find({'data.scheduleId': 95}) doesnt work

Comment: UPDATE: i get it working following the question submit by Joe, since find didnt give a readable result for querying i did collection.findOneAndDelete({'data.scheduleId': id}) and it worked