# How to use find method with nested documents in mongodb with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js

I have my data structured like this that I get from `localhost:3000/api/notes/[noteTitle]/note2`

```
{
  "data": [
      {
          "_id": "62ff418fa4adfb3a957a2847",
          "title": "first-note2",
          "note": { "_id": "62ff399da4adfb3a957a2808", "title": "first" },
      },
      {
          "_id": "631af43b054a6aef1a7c4f08",
          "title": "first-note22",
          "note": { "_id": "62ff399da4adfb3a957a2808", "title": "first" },
      },
      {
          "_id": "631af504054a6aef1a7c4f11",
          "title": "second-note22",
          "note": { "_id": "62ff3a10a4adfb3a957a2817", "title": "second" },
      }
  ]
}
```

When I send an API request to `localhost:3000/api/notes/first/note2` I want to fetch only those data that have the title "first" in the note object.

I tried doing it like this in the API pages:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { query: { noteTitle }, method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const notes = await Note2.find({"note.title": noteTitle}).populate("note");
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: notes });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      break;

    default:
      res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      break;
  }
};
```

But it returns an entry array even though I should get two matches.

Where did I go wrong?

**Edit:** This is how my Note2 schema looks:

```
const Note2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, unique: true },
  note: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Note" },
});
module.exports = mongoose.models.Note2 || mongoose.model("Note2", Note2Schema);
```

And my Note Schema:

```
const NoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, unique: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.models.Note || mongoose.model("Note", NoteSchema);
```

**Edit 2:** I found this in the mongoose docs. Seems like I can't find any data that I'm populating and using that populated data in the find method.

Is there any workaround solution for what I want to achieve?

`In general, there is no way to make populate() filter stories based on properties of the story's author. For example, the below query won't return any results, even though author is populated.`

```
const story = await Story.
  findOne({ 'author.name': 'Ian Fleming' }).
  populate('author').
  exec();
story; // null
```

Answer (score 1):

"note" is an object property which is inside of the array named "data". So your query should be like this -

```
const notes = await Note2.find({"data.note.title": noteTitle}).populate("note");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Instead of returning two values, it returns all of it when I tried what you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure what value is in noteTitle but try this const notes = await Note2.find({"data.note.title": "first"})

Comment: no, it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

As I found in the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions), there is no way to make populate() filter notes based on the properties of the note2's title.

```
const notes = await Note2.find({ })
  .populate({
    path: 'note',
    match: { title: noteTitle },
  })
  .exec();
```

And my goal was to get only the two data that have the "first" string on the `note.title` in it. So I found a workaround solution using a second filter after I get all the Note2 data from the database.

```
const notes = await Note2.find({}).populate({ path: "note" })

const selectedNote2 = notes.map((singleNote) => {
  if (singleNote.note.title === noteTitle) {
    return singleNote
  }
  return []
})

res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: selectedNote2});
```

I don't know if there's a better solution than this one.